# error handling azure cli with python script

Tags: python, azure-devops

I have been trying to figure out error handling for azure cli commands within a python script. I have seen work-arounds for powershell being able to pull out the exit codes after the command runs, but it was specific for powershell.

My scenario that I am running into is, running az devops cli commands in my python script to create a team. using the az.cli module, the command would be as follows:

```
az('devops team create --name ' + '"' + team_name + '"' + ' --description ' + '"' + description + '"' + ' --org ' + org_url + ' --project ' + '"' + project_name + '"')
```

When it encounters an error, I am unable to do anything to catch it because the error doesn't occur in the call, it is the response.

az call to create team --> exit code 1, error response team name already exists.
The call was successful so doesn't trigger exception in the script.

try..except does not work due to call being successful.

```
[2022-08-01T23:32:45.498Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2022-08-01T23:32:46.287Z] command args: devops team create --name {} --description {} --org {} --project {}
[2022-08-01T23:32:46.667Z] extension name: azure-devops
[2022-08-01T23:32:46.668Z] extension version: 0.25.0
[2022-08-01T23:32:46.681Z] received PAT from environment variable
[2022-08-01T23:32:46.683Z] Creating connection with personal access token.
[2022-08-01T23:32:46.901Z] Suppress exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 "some code"

[2022-08-01T23:32:47.599Z] The team
[2022-08-01T23:32:47.603Z] The team
[2022-08-01T23:32:47.604Z] exit code: 1
[2022-08-01T23:32:47.612Z] Executed 'Functions.FunctionApp' (Failed, Id="an id", Duration=2117ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

`az` returns a `namedtuple` rather than raise exceptions, and the format of the `namedtuple` is:

```
('exit_code', 'result_dict', 'log')
```

So you can destructure the return value and get the return code.

Here's an extremely contrived example where it tries to create the team and then checks the return value, and stops the loop if it gets a non-zero return code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from az.cli import az

team_name = "FancyNewTeam"
desc = "A team description"
org = "https://dev.azure.com/myorg"
project = "slackcat"

cmd = f"devops team create --name {team_name} --description {desc} --organization={org} --project {project}"

while True:
    ret, res, logs = az(cmd)
    if ret == 0:
        print("Command succeeded!")
    else:
        print("Command failed. Stopping loop")
        break
```

And the output on my account is...

```
❯ python az_script.py
Command succeeded!
Command failed. Stopping loop
```